# Creating an Insert Operation, however AFTER converting from the Model StudentView -> Student And Pass into InsertStudentAsync , the func returns null

Tags: c#, automapper, crud, xunit

I was trying to unit test a simple Create Operation using the Auto Mapper, I don't understand why the null is being returned.

The Data Model or Entity Model or Model that is used to Access the Database:

```
   public partial class Student
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string IdentityNumber { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset BirthDate { get; set; }
        public int Gender { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset UpdatedDate { get; set; }
        public Guid CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public Guid UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    }
```

The Model that is used for the Business Logic is:

```
   public class StudentView
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string IdentityNumber { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset BirthDate { get; set; }
        public Gender Gender { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset UpdatedDate { get; set; }
        public Guid CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public Guid UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    }

 public enum Gender
    {
        Male,
        Female,
        Other
    }
```

The Function that is being used to Call the operation:

```
 public async Task<StudentView> RegisterStudentAsync(StudentView student)
        {
            Student inputStudent =
                    this.mapper.Map<Student>(student);

            Student storageStudent =
                 await this.storageBroker.InsertStudentAsync(inputStudent);

            StudentView storageStudentView =
                this.mapper.Map<StudentView>(storageStudent);

            return storageStudentView;
        }
```

The AutoMapper Configuration using Profile:

```
 public class MappingProfiles : Profile
    {
        public MappingProfiles() =>
            CreateMap<StudentView, Student>()
                .ReverseMap();
    }
```

This is Added in the Startup to make my project know this profile:

```
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(MappingProfiles));
```

There is no Inversion of Controll (IOC), so I ve instantiated the mapper configuration and made it known as a singleton that a mapperProfile exist, so that I can use the configured mapping.

```
 public partial class StudentServiceTests
    {
        private readonly Mock<ILoggingBroker> loggingBrockerMock;
        private readonly Mock<IStorageBroker> storageBrokerMock;
        private readonly Mock<IDateTimeBroker> dateTimeBrokerMock;
        private readonly IMapper mapperMock;
        private readonly IStudentService studentService;

        public  StudentServiceTests()
        {
            this.loggingBrockerMock = new Mock<ILoggingBroker>();
            this.storageBrokerMock = new Mock<IStorageBroker>();
            this.dateTimeBrokerMock = new Mock<IDateTimeBroker>();

            var configurationMapper = new MapperConfiguration(
                 options =>
                    options.AddProfile(new MappingProfiles()));

            IMapper mapper = configurationMapper.CreateMapper();
            this.mapperMock = mapper;

            this.studentService = new StudentService(
                loggingBroker: this.loggingBrockerMock.Object,
                dateTimeBroker: this.dateTimeBrokerMock.Object,
                storageBroker: this.storageBrokerMock.Object,
                mapper:this.mapperMock);
        }
```

The Unit test that was created:

```
 [Fact]
        public async Task ShouldRegisterStudentWhenPassedIn()
        {
            // Arrange - Given
            StudentView randomStudentView = CreateRandomStudent();
            StudentView inputStudentView = randomStudentView;

            Student inputStudent =
                this.mapperMock.Map<StudentView, Student>(inputStudentView);

            Student returnedStorageStudent = inputStudent;
            StudentView expectedStudentView = inputStudentView;

            this.storageBrokerMock.Setup(broker =>
                 broker.InsertStudentAsync(inputStudent))
                    .ReturnsAsync(returnedStorageStudent);

            // When - Act
             StudentView actualStudent =
         await this.studentService.RegisterStudentAsync(inputStudentView);

            // Assert - Then
            actualStudent.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedStudentView);

            this.storageBrokerMock.Verify(brocker =>
                brocker.InsertStudentAsync(inputStudent),
                    Times.Once);

            this.storageBrokerMock.VerifyNoOtherCalls();
            this.loggingBrockerMock.VerifyNoOtherCalls();
            this.dateTimeBrokerMock.VerifyNoOtherCalls();
        }
```

the Result that is being obtained:

```
public async Task<StudentView> RegisterStudentAsync(StudentView student)
        {
             // converts correctly

            Student inputStudent =
                    this.mapper.Map<Student>(student);

            // the storageStudent is Null, even though the inputStudent has 
             // values in the properties

            Student storageStudent =
                 await this.storageBroker.InsertStudentAsync(inputStudent);

            StudentView storageStudentView =
                this.mapper.Map<StudentView>(storageStudent);

            return storageStudentView;
        }
```

The Function that is used to Hit the Database:

```
 public async Task<Student> InsertStudentAsync(Student student)
        {
            EntityEntry<Student> entityEntryStudent = 
                await this.Students.AddAsync(student);

            await this.SaveChangesAsync();

            return entityEntryStudent.Entity;
        }
```

If you like to reproduce, I can share my repository.

Comment: What is the definition of your InsertStudentAsync method?

Comment: Added the Function that is hitting the Db.

Comment: By reverse logic if `entityEntryStudent.Entity` is NULL so the Entity is not being tracked. By definition the `AddAsync()` method should "Begin tracking the given entity, and any other reachable entities that are not already being tracked, in the Added state such that they will be inserted into the database when SaveChanges() is called.", so may I assume there are no changes in the database even after SaveChanges() is called? If so check if the QueryTrackingBehavior is not set to NoTracking: `context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;` otherwise no idea :)

Comment: context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;  i set this to the selectStudentById,this was what made me lost, when i direcly inject the  Model: Student into the  await 
 this.storageBroker.InsertStudentAsync(inputStudent);                                         
 instead of converting from StudentView to Student, it works 100%, however,when i convert and it enters the function it returns a null, debuged it, it is like it is never entering the function just skipping it.

Comment: I'm sorry if I did not understand your comment correctly (English is not my first language), but you have to remove the `.NoTracking` flag from the context if you want to make changes to the entities in the database. Did I understand correctly that you use the flag when you get the entity from the database (as you said: _i set this to the selectStudentById_)? If so, remove it and try again.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `null`, because mock is not configured correctly.

```
this.storageBrokerMock
    .Setup(broker => broker.InsertStudentAsync(inputStudent))
    .ReturnsAsync(returnedStorageStudent);
```

Configuration above will return `returnedStorageStudent` only when reference of `inputStudent` is passed to the `InsertStudentAsync` method.

Notice that in "production" code mapper will create new instance of `Student`.

So question is not about Automapper or Xunit, but about the mock framework you are using - How to configure mock to verify that correct object passed to the method?

Test can look like below

```
[Fact]
public async Task ShouldRegisterStudentWhenPassedIn()
{
    var givenView = CreateRandomStudent();
    var createdId = Guid.NewGuid();

    this.storageBrokerMock
        .Setup(broker => broker.InsertStudentAsync(It.IsAny<Student>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(given =>
        {
            Id = createdId,
            UserId = given.UserId,
            // ..
        });

    var actualView = await this.studentService.RegisterStudentAsync(givenView);

    var expectedView = new StudentView
    {
        Id = createdId,
        UserId = givenView.UserId,
        // ..            
    }
    actualView.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedView);
}
```

Comment: Thank You, it worked after applying the changes that u suggested, I want to ask what is the point of the automapper in the Xunit ?

Comment: @Bdruid, Xunit doesn't require Automapper.

Comment: Thanks, For the help.